# Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to check if an object is null,doing

```
let hostels = null;
if (hostels[0] !== null && hostels[0].name !== null) {
}
```

but I have this error:

```
 error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

Comment: try `if (hotels && hotels[0] && hostels[0].name) `

Comment: You are referring to 2 different variables: `hotels[0]` and `hostels[0]`

Comment: @MaximilianFixl I would only suppress it, if you are 100% sure that hotels cannot be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error is because you are trying to access an element of an array when your object is not an array, it is null. Your check is essentially saying `null[0] !== null`

As Sourabh Somani suggested, checking that the object is not 'falsey' should resolve the issue

```js
let hostels = null;
if (hostels && hostels[0] !== null && hostels[0].name !== null) {
}
```

A 'falsey' check will determine if your object is a false value for example:

```js
let hostels = null;
if(hostels) {  } // false

let hostels = undefined;
if(hostels) { } // false 

let hostels = [];
if(hostels) { } // true
```